# Stack Overflow is not novice-friendly

Tags: support, specific-question, new-users

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689311/stackoverflow-help-needed-closed) (now 10k-only), it has negative score and everyone is accusing me of trolling. The site also won't let me ask questions at a faster rate.

I feel this site is not friendly to novice programmers or novice users.

Comment: As a courtesy to other readers, here's the question in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689311/stackoverflow-help-needed-closed

Comment: I don't know, Stack Overflow seems nice enough to [me](http://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice). ;)

Comment: @RedDwight Isn't that something? It seems like *I* am the "troll" in question.

Comment: @NullUserException - You *fiend*! Luckily someone was able to immediately see through your ruse and point to the fact that you went to the trouble to create an alternate persona to draw attention to something that had been in your profile (if memory serves me) for a while...

Comment: Wow.  A double troll; that's sort of like http://bit.ly/7JJSz8

Comment: @tvanfosson: "This video is not available in your country." Are you trolling me or what?

Comment: @Reg - try this one http://bit.ly/19phLt, or, better yet, here http://bit.ly/6kwKHF

Comment: Rick Astley has a VEVO??

Comment: @tvanfosson: Thanks for the wonderful music... Awww good ol' Rick.

Answer (score 7):

So what? If they accuse you of being a troll you need to learn they are on the internet, they can't do much harm (except for your rep, but it's pretty useless). We already discussed the reason for time limit. Also, Stack Overflow is not a place for asking developers to make your apps (like your facebook question).

What I recommend you do is get a teacher. You have to pay them but, they will listen to you no matter what and even if you ask stuff like your facebook question they will guide you along the way to help you. Unless your really dedicated to learning programming by yourself you need a teacher, and you need to learn the basics too. Knowing Dreamweaver is not even directly programming related (it does if you are a serious web developer but, its also for newbs that just want to make a website like me, and based on your facebook question I have a strong belief you do not know much or you atleast need a good review).

Anyway, once you review the basics look up some stuff about your project and so some research. The truth is that Q&As and forums are nice but, you should learn to be more and more **self-sufficient**  and the only way to do so is to stop asking questions every time you have one and start learning to Google. Yeah, Google is just that great of a tool. You should use it more often. In fact, I think you should learn to search better by just trying to find something and see if you can find it (and if one search doesn't work make a try a different way). As a programmer, you need to get really good at this because it allows you to be more productive by not having to wait for answers.

You can not ask us to help make a whole program, that's what you use your previous programming knowledge and Googleing skills for. You need to ask more ask specific questions. General rule of thumb: if you could hire a programmer to do it, don't ask it. I mean, you could hire a programmer to make a facebook app/webpage but, you probably wouldn't hire one to help you with a syntax error such as missing a missing a semicolon (except that might be a little too simple to ask on this site also). Also, one more thing, don't not try either, just asking is stupid with out Googling and trying some code before you ask, and I found that even some of my questions if I had Google a little bit more I probably could have found it.